# $L^2$ integrability

Tags: integration, hilbert-spaces

Consider the function $f(x)=x^{-1/2}$ for $0<x<1$, and $0$ else. Let $\{r_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ an enumeration of the rationals. Let $F(x)= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{-n}f(x-r_n)$. Prove that $F(x)$ is not $L^2$ integrable in any interval [a,b].

What I've found is that $F(x)$ is unbounded on every interval [a,b], but I don't know how to connect it. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose any $n$ such that $a < r_n < b$. Then
$$|F(x)| \geq 2^{-n}|f(x-r_n)|$$
so for all $x \in (r_n, b)$ we have
$$|F(x)|^2 \geq 2^{-2n}|f(x-r_n)|^2 = \frac{2^{-2n}}{x-r_n}$$
Then
$$\begin{aligned}
\int_{a}^{b} |F(x)|^2 dx &\geq \int_{r_n}^{b}|F(x)|^2 dx \\
&\geq 2^{-2n}\int_{r_n}^{b}|f(x-r_n)|^2 dx \\
& = 2^{-2n}\int_{r_n}^{b}\frac{1}{x-r_n} dx \\
&= 2^{-2n} \int_0^{b - r_n} \frac{1}{x} dx \\
&= \infty
\end{aligned}$$